# New Strapi Application won’t run

Tags: node.js, strapi

I’m just new to Strapi and I followed the steps in the Strapi Documentation in creating a new project with Strapi and started with this `npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart`

After creation, it opened the localhost page on my browser and it showed an `This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 426` error

[image]

This is what my terminal looks like:
[image]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the solutions you could

1. try killing port on 1337 and run `yarn develop`
2. change the port number on `./config/server.js` to another port like 1331 and run

It is most likely because the port is already in use

Comment: I already changed the por number on the server.js into 1331 then I run it and it stills show 'http://localhost:1337/admin'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Setup new project via: `npx create-strapi-app test_bug --quickstart`
2. If the installation is completed, then execute: `npm run develop or yarn run develop`

It works for me and I think it could work for you too.